# Two SQL Joins, Two Different Results

Tags: mysql, sql

Hows is it possible for these two queries to be different. I mean the first query didn't include all the rows from my left table so I put the conditions within the join part.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as opens, hours.hour as point 
FROM hours 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tracking ON hours.hour = HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tracking.open_date)) 
WHERE tracking.campaign_id = 83 
AND tracking.open_date < 1299538799 
AND tracking.open_date > 1299452401 
GROUP BY hours.hour
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as opens, hours.hour as point 
FROM hours 
LEFT JOIN tracking ON hours.hour = HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tracking.open_date)) 
AND tracking.campaign_id = 83 
AND tracking.open_date < 1299538799 
AND tracking.open_date > 1299452401 
GROUP BY hours.hour
```

The difference is that the first query gives me 18 rows where there are no rows between point 17 to 22. But when I run the second query, it shows the fully 24 rows but for rows between 17 and 22 it has a value of **1**! I would of expected it to be 0 or NULL? If it really is 1 should it not have appeared in the first query?

How has this happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `COUNT(*)`, which will count every row in your result set (as it's written), since even without data in `tracking`, you do have data in `hours`.

Try changing `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(tracking.open_date)` (or any non-nullable column within `tracking`; it doesn't matter which one).

Comment: Aaah! I missed that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @erikkallen: You'd think so, but it's not the case across all RDBMS engines. To my knowledge, both the MyISAM and InnoDB engines within MySQL (as well as the MS SQL Server engine) do not count instances of `null`. I can't speak for others, but it would seem that it solved the OP's problem.

Answer (score 5):

the first JOIN is really an INNER JOIN, the outer joined table should not appear in the WHERE clause like you have in the top query, instead of COUNT(*), pick a column from the outer joined table

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(*)` counts the number of rows resulted in the query.

You can use `count(tracking.open_date)`, basically any column from tracking table (right table)

Comment: 3 correct answers - it will have to come down to time. You were the quickest.

Comment: -1; `left join` and `left outer join` are synonymous. All `left` and `right` joins are `outer` joins automatically. Inner joins (what you describe first) cannot be designated as `left` or `right` because rows are only included if they match on both sides.

Comment: @Abs: You can actually hover over the "5 mins ago" (or whatever it says) on an answer to see the time posted. Just for the record, this answer was posted two minutes after mine.

Comment: `left join` means `left outer join`, *not* inner. There is no such thing as a `left inner` or `right inner` join, as such a thing doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Adam - Hmmm... Ok, edited my answer. Thanks, I am probably getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first query will do an outer join, with some rows containing NULL in all tables from the tracking table. Then it will apply a filter on those tracking columns, and since they are null, the corresponding row from the result set will be filtered out.

The second query will do a proper outer join on all columns.

Comment: This correctly addresses why the first query behaves like an inner join (since, as you point out, it basically *is*), but it does not address his issue with getting a value for `COUNT` when he has no values in `tracking`.